# RED5 server with HTML5 Player

Tags: java, html, video-streaming, html5-video, red5

I'm using RED5 server to stream video and I want to play them through HTML5 player. Is that possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Red5 1.0.1 supports H.264 as stated on http://www.red5.org/features/ .
    Streaming Audio/Video (FLV and MP3)
    Recording Client Streams (FLV only)
    Shared Objects
    Live Stream Publishing (live h264 supported now)
    Remoting ( AMF0/ AMF3)